# Running openstack-install with MAAS and Juju - Keystone errors while "waiting for deployed services to be in a ready state"

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack (Liberty) to my machines using the openstack-installer's multi option on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, but I'm not having a lot of success.

As far as I can tell, MAAS 1.9.3 is set up correctly - I can commission, allocate, and deploy nodes, then SSH into them, no problem.

When I run openstack-install, it bootstraps Juju on one node, then starts three others, on which it starts deploying the various OpenStack charms. Each charm deploys in succession.

(Excerpt from Keystone, but there's a section like this for each charm)

```
[INFO: 06-24 11:15:23, consoleui.py:51] Pending charms to deploy: Keystone, RabbitMQ Server, Controller, Neutron, Glance - Simplestreams Image Sync, Openstack Dashboard, Glance, Neutron OpenVSwitch, Neutron API, Compute
[INFO: 06-24 11:15:23, consoleui.py:37] Checking if Keystone is deployed
[INFO: 06-24 11:15:23, consoleui.py:37] Deploying Keystone to machine lxc:3
[DEBUG: 06-24 11:15:23, __init__.py:221] charm_config = {'juju-gui': {'password': 'password'}, 'neutron-openvswitch': None, 'neutron-gateway': {'instance-mtu': 1400, 'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'ext-port': 'eth1'}, 'glance-simplestreams-sync': {'use_swift': False}, 'nova-cloud-controller': {'network-manager': 'Neutron', 'quantum-security-groups': 'yes', 'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'console-access-protocol': 'novnc'}, 'heat': {'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty'}, 'ceilometer': {'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty'}, 'ceilometer-agent': {'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty'}, 'neutron-api': {'neutron-security-groups': True, 'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'l2-population': False}, 'openstack-dashboard': {'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty'}, 'ceph-radosgw': {'source': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'use-embedded-webserver': True}, 'ceph-osd': {'osd-reformat': 'yes', 'source': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'osd-devices': '/dev/sdb'}, 'swift-storage': {'block-device': '/etc/swift/storage.img|2G', 'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'zone': 1}, 'keystone': {'admin-user': 'admin', 'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'admin-password': 'password'}, 'glance': {'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty'}, 'ceph': {'source': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'fsid': '4df47d30-cbf3-45d9-a485-27996ab6998e', 'monitor-secret': 'AQBilclUKG9RIRAAlFP9bohec06c+e7lfCRGrw=='}, 'cinder': {'glance-api-version': 2, 'block-device': '/var/lib/cinder-sdb.img|5G', 'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty'}, 'nova-compute': {'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty'}, 'swift-proxy': {'replicas': 3, 'openstack-origin': 'cloud:trusty-liberty', 'zone-assignment': 'auto'}, 'mysql': {'max-connections': 25000, 'dataset-size': '512M'}}
[DEBUG: 06-24 11:15:23, __init__.py:276] calling deploy(keystone, keystone, 1, {}, lxc:3)
[INFO: 06-24 11:15:30, consoleui.py:37] Deployed Keystone.
[DEBUG: 06-24 11:15:30, core.py:466] Issued deploy for Keystone
```

Once all services are deployed, we wait for them to become ready. They come off the pending list one or two at a time.

Keystone comes off the pending list - appearing to ready up - but eventually comes back with an error when only glance-simplestreams-sync remains. The installer hangs here indefinitely.

```
[INFO: 06-24 11:16:35, consoleui.py:37] Waiting for deployed services to be in a ready state.
[INFO: 06-24 11:16:35, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, rabbitmq-server:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending, neutron-gateway:pending, glance:pending, nova-cloud-controller:pending, mysql:pending, nova-compute:pending, openstack-dashboard:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 11:19:45, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, rabbitmq-server:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending, glance:pending, nova-cloud-controller:pending, mysql:pending, nova-compute:pending, openstack-dashboard:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 11:21:31, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, rabbitmq-server:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending, glance:pending, nova-cloud-controller:pending, mysql:pending, openstack-dashboard:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 11:44:03, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending, glance:pending, nova-cloud-controller:pending, mysql:pending, openstack-dashboard:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 12:03:46, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending, glance:pending, mysql:pending, openstack-dashboard:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 12:04:50, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending, mysql:pending, openstack-dashboard:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 12:14:41, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending, mysql:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 12:16:27, core.py:580] Checking availability of neutron-api:pending, glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 12:17:30, core.py:580] Checking availability of glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 12:18:13, core.py:580] Checking availability of glance-simplestreams-sync:pending 
[INFO: 06-24 12:32:39, core.py:580] Checking availability of glance-simplestreams-sync:pending, keystone:error 
[INFO: 06-24 12:40:24, core.py:580] Checking availability of keystone:error
```

Any ideas why this error might be occurring, or what I need to do to get around it?

(Please let me know if there's any further info I can provide. I'm new to this and learning as I go, so I'm unsure where to find more specific or useful logs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to complete my installation successfully by re-running the hook in a second terminal.

```
juju resolved --retry keystone/0
```